# Tengo problemas para obtener un promedio

Tags: sql, sqlite

Aquí explico la situación:
Tengo las siguientes tablas (Copie tal cual el código que aparece cuando se da click en Modify Table):

```
CREATE TABLE "Estudiantes" (
    "IDEstudiante"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("IDEstudiante")
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE "Asesores" (
    "IDAsesor"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("IDAsesor")
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE "Asesorias" (
    "IDAsesorias"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Dia"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Cod_estudiante"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Cod_asesor"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("IDAsesorias"),
    FOREIGN KEY("Cod_asesor") REFERENCES "Asesores"("IDAsesor"),
    FOREIGN KEY("Cod_estudiante") REFERENCES "Estudiantes"("IDEstudiante")
);
```

**Nota Importante**: los días yo cuando les estoy otorgando un valor les pongo: Lunes, Martes, Miércoles....

En esta última tabla relaciona las 2 primeras tablas que cree.
Para hacer pruebas introduje varios datos tanto en estudiantes como asesores para hacer varias "Asesorias" y hacer las pruebas de código.

El problema que tengo es uno de obtener el promedio de asesorias de cada día, yo lo plantee así:

```
SELECT sum(Dia='Lunes')/count(distinct(Dia)) as Lunes FROM Asesorias;
```

de esa manera para cada día, pero al obtener el resultado **NO obtengo los decimales** ¿Hay alguna otra manera de hacer talque si aparezcan los decimales o es porque estoy usando SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es porque el operador `/` entre enteros devuelve un cociente entero. Por ejemplo, 7/5 = 1 lo cual es correcto, ya que tu cociente es 1 y el residuo es 2. Lo que necesitas es convertir el divisor o el dividendo como un tipo de dato con decimales, para que tu división te devuelva decimales también.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT cast(sum(Dia='Lunes') as float)/count(distinct(Dia)) as Lunes FROM Asesorias;
```

También puedes utilizar la función [avg(](https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-avg.php)) que ya incluye sqlite para el mismo propósito.